# Postgresql table, can we skip transactionId management

Tags: postgresql

I have a large (but simple) table with billions of rows. There are 3 columns X (int), Y (int), Z(int). Each row has a unique pair (X, Y).  The data is constantly changing (especially value Z).

Majority of the actions on the table are

1. query (given X value, Y value, find the average Z value of the matching rows).
2. update value Z given X value, Y value

occasionally it does insertion and deletion (very rare).

Currently the auto vacuum is not able to keep up and it takes days and often had to be killed.  I know the auto vacuuming is important since it needs to 1) deal with transactionID wrapping, 2) recycle the dead tuples,
but we would like skip all the transactionID stuff and just update the original matching row based on X, Y  with a newer value Z in place (no need to delete the row and create a new row).

I know doing so will risk the integrity of the query, when a select query is executed, a row is updated/deleted/added, but the nature of the application is that this inaccuracy is not a big problem.

Wonder if it's possible to disable transactionID and hence updating will be in-place (instead of delete + insert)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Z part of an index? If not you, those update should be eligible as HOT updates

Comment: Z column is not an index. Thanks for mentioning HOT update, will check it it out.

Comment: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/